# Info mode isearch across nodes

Tags: search, isearch, info

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/info/Search-Text.html

> Instead of using s in Emacs Info and in the stand-alone Info, you can use an incremental search started with C-s or C-r. It can search through multiple Info nodes. See Incremental Search in The GNU Emacs Manual. In Emacs, you can disable this behavior by setting the variable Info-isearch-search to nil (see Emacs Info-mode Variables).

I have set `Info-isearch-search` to `t`, but when I call `isearch-forward`, it only searches forward within the current node.

Comment: Check its value with `C-h v Info-isearch-search` to make sure it is set correctly. How are you setting it? You might want to use the Customize interface and make sure that you click `Apply and Save`.

Comment: What @NickD said. But first, try starting Emacs using `emacs -Q`, if you haven't already. If that alone fixes the problem then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You need to `C-s` again *after* a failure to move to the next node with a hit.

Comment: Thanks @phils, I had to press it three times, now it works :) The variable is all set correctly and verified.